# HTML5 game pases when you go to another tab

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

I'm making a simple game and I use `requestAnimationFrame`. Now the problem is that each I change to another tab the game pauses and when I return the game continues.

This is really bad because the game is multiplayer and restarting the game each time a user switches to another tab doesn't seem like a great idea.

Do any of you have any idea how I can keep the game active, while the user change to another tab?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched online about this? As far as I know it's a quite common issue. Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441483/how-to-keep-a-javascript-html5-game-running-when-the-window-loses-focus) help?

Comment: @TomTsagk That question is unanswered!

Comment: @Philipp Oops didn't notice that, however one of the comments specifies why `requestAnimationFrame` is not working and `setTimeout` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your game's code into logic code and drawing code.

Put the logic code into a function which you execute at regular intervals with [`SetInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Intervals still get executed when the tab is inactive. Note that if you use SetInterval on the main `window` object, then most browsers will throttle it when the tab is inactive. When you are using a game loop with a variable time-step (you check how much time elapsed since the last update and take it into account when moving things) then this should not be a problem. But if you want to use a fixed timestep, then you can get around this by using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). Web workers can use intervals which do not get throttled in inactive tabs.

Your drawing code should stay in the method you pass to `requestAnimationFrame`. You *can* do canvas drawing in your interval method, but using requestAnimationFrame is recommended. It should be easier for the browser's rendering engine (whether this translates to a tangible performance benefit is implementation-specific) and there is little reason to waste the client's resources on drawing frames nobody is going to see.

Comment: But is window.setInterval not throttled when the tab is inactive? Also you say execute it at regular intervals but should I first check what is each clients frame rate or should I use the same regular interval for everyone because there may be a discrepancy?

Comment: @CupOfCoffee Yes, but I assumed that since you implied you use requestAnimationFrame for your game logic (which means the calls per second are unpredictable either) you have a variable timestep. If you want to make sure that your interval gets priority even if your tab is inactive, attach the interval to a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).

Comment: I experimented with this today and I made an event ```visibilitychange``` just to see whether my ```update``` func runs even in the background with ```setTimeout``` and it turns out it ran 17 times in 10 seconds which is not acceptable and pauses the game in the same way ```requestAnimationsFrame``` did - it seems for now the way to go would be a web worker.